# Create Visual Studio 2015 Unmanaged C++ Service

Tags: c++, visual-studio, service, visual-studio-2015, unmanaged

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and would like to create a service. The only thing I can see is "Add New Project" - "Visual C++" - "ATL", but while that looks like the wizard has an "Application type:" "Service (EXE)" option, I'm not creating a COM object and this service has no need for ActiveX. I also see I could do it in C#, but the requirements don't allow for .NET.

I do see various examples online, but they all are simply copies of a project that was already created. I'd prefer to start from scratch and it seems older version of Visual Studio allowed this. What is the recommended way to create an unmanaged C++ service with VS2015?

Comment: I don't think there is a widely recommended approach. I use Brute Force: Create a regular executable project and add all service support by hand.

Comment: I assume "Win32 Console Application" to start then and copy in the required boilerplate?

Comment: Playing with it, Console App does seem to be the smarter choice. I've been selecting Win32 and customizing it to be nearly identical to Console App.

Comment: Cool. I'll go with that. Thanks.